# How to enable batching in azure pipeline for specific branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

While creating a pipeline, I want to enable batching for specific branches and not so for other branches, is there a way of doing so in microsoft azure pipelines ?

If I enable `batch:true` it runs for all branches and if I remove it, it doesn't work for any branches

I have it like

```
trigger:
    batch: true
    branches:
        include:
            - master
            - A*
            - B*
            - C*
            - D*
            - TEST
            - Develop
```

I don't want batching only for `master` branch but want batching for other branches, can this be achieved  without creating seperate pipeline yml just to enable `batch:true` in the same pipeline ?

Comment: I don't think is available :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure DevOps Service, the yaml build just trigger and batch for current branch.

For example:

If we create YAML build in the master branch, it will create `azure-pipelines.yml` file in the master branch. Edit the YAML build definition, such as:

```
trigger:
    batch: true
    branches:
        include:
            - master
            - TEST
```

Switch to **TEST** branch and edit the `azure-pipelines.yml` file, such as:

```
trigger:
    batch: true
    branches:
        include:
            - master
```

Then push code in the TEST branch, it will not trigger the build and queue a new build.

> I want to enable batching for specific branches and not so for other branches,

As a work around, we could switch the branch, edit the YAML file and enable batching for specific branch. This will not affect other branches.

**Note**: Since the file is different in the different branches, the file azure-pipelines.yml will conflict when we create PR

**Update**

Thanks for @Hiteshdua1 sharing.

The solution is create different yaml build definitions, then we could enable batching for specific branches and not so for other branches.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the issue, If I am creating a branch off master, I need not run my CI pipeline for every commit and instead use batching, But for every commit in master, I don't want to enable batching for my specific use case.

This approach wouldn't be scalable , since there could be N no of branches created.

The scalable approach of creating 2 different pipelines, just feel too much duplicate code to maintain for just this use case.

Comment: You could create the YAML build based on this workaround, it should solve your issue, there is no better way now.

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: I created two YAML, rather than this, because we need to run this for everyBranch.

Comment: Hi @Hiteshdua1, Thanks for the sharing, I have edited the answer and add your solution, would you mind accepting it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)